# how to prepare layOut notifcation Listview in android

Tags: android

This is my adapter list-view item xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/notificationuserimage"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/index" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="#505050"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="#202020"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dip"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:src="@drawable/accepticon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dip"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:src="@drawable/rejecticon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/runnimage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/drive"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rejectedrequest"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Rejected"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/revresetime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Just 5 Minute Ago"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Current screen :[image]

how to set  list view item in adapter i am not able to set item Like given screen :

Screen we have to create [image]

please set my list view item so that i can set my current layout to given layout am Unable to do and face some issue so please help and suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout: (change ids for your accommodation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#505050"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="Request for traveling"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#202020"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="asd has requested to travel with you"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:src="drawable/accepticon"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:src="@drawable/rejecticon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/revresetime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Just 5 Minute Ago"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rejectedrequest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Rejected"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/revresetime"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/runnimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:src="@drawable/drive"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/revresetime"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rejectedrequest"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rejectedrequest"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

To achive that background effect use this line before the return on the getView of your adapter:

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 ? getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_back) : getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok wait let me try this

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentStart' in package 'android'  error is coming  <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView

Comment: please check mY issue

Comment: Remove android:layout_alignParentStart="true". In your getview of the adapter did you set the root when you inflate the view? Or you just set null? Remember to pass the parent as the root view and false as the third parameter of the inflate method.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/BJ3dM46V9mGJFQsgnkuiPa here is my code please tell where am doing mistake

Comment: Replace `convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.notifcationlistitem, null);` for `convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.notifcationlistitem, parent,false);`

Comment: See there are 4 control in Linear Layout (linear2 ) 2 visible and 2 invisiible i have to set that also coz we have applied onClick function on which we have to invisible and visible respectably

Comment: Since you don't shown them in the images I don't know where to put them. But I will add them also and update my answer. Check it in a while

Comment: yes plz u use accrding ur theme but i want image controls according my Screen please

Comment: even i have changed its id then also its coming

Comment: You don't need to change any id as far as I know. All the ids are the same as yours and there is no view missing. Make sure you copied and pasted the xml correct

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_toEndOf' in package 'android'  error still coming whihl i have changed in getview

Comment: layout_toEndOf was added in API Level 17. If you are using a lower api level use layout_toRightOf instead. This is used for Right to Left screens. Remove all those lines with that since the layout_toRightOf is already defined

Comment: after click accept and reject accept and reject icon is hide But not at same place of date i have to hide accept and reject and someplace am displaying another image

Comment: Since this is using a relative layout if you set GONE as visibility the other components that have a reference to it will lose its anchors. My advice is to set the visibility to INVISIBLE instead of gone. Otherwise if you don't want to do this you can set `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"`in those imageviews and that should help too

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentEnd' in package 'android'  error is coming

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: There find the Solution